# 'The optimizer cannot recognize variable SimpleMolGANGenerator/dense_40/kernel:0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I was reading about GAN networks for molecules and got [this code](https://www.kaggle.com/code/shivanshuman/gans-for-molecules/notebook) for tox21 dataset from kaggle. When I try to run it in [collab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/examples/tutorials/Generating_molecules_with_MolGAN.ipynb#scrollTo=w8-gGyL3TMft) , it gives me an error in the line:

```
gan.fit_gan(iterbatches(25), generator_steps=0.2, checkpoint_interval=5000)
```

---

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 gan.fit_gan(iterbatches(25), generator_steps=0.2, checkpoint_interval=5000)
2 generated_data = gan.predict_gan_generator(1000)

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py in _update_step(self, gradient, variable)
230             return
231         if self._var_key(variable) not in self._index_dict:
--> 232             raise KeyError(
233                 f"The optimizer cannot recognize variable {variable.name}. "
234                 "This usually means you are trying to call the optimizer to "

KeyError: 'The optimizer cannot recognize variable SimpleMolGANGenerator/dense/kernel:0. This usually means you are trying to call the optimizer to update different parts of the model separately. Please call `optimizer.build(variables)` with the full list of trainable variables before the training loop or use legacy optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam.'

Any way to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but with AdamW optimizer.

My error was that I was creating my model and runing fit inside a loop (because cross-validation) and I was creating the optimizer outside de loop.